# Maven - why maven won't download the dependency pom in addition to the jar file

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a Maven project. One of my dependencies is a zip file. Maven downloads this zip file to the local repository but the pom file is not there too. How can I instruct Maven to download also the pom file? the type of my dependency is zip.

**the pom file exists in the remote repository.** 
the pom file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.g.g</groupId>
<artifactId>art</artifactId>
<name>art</name>
<version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<build>

    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>

                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>createZip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>

</build>
```

the deploy command:

```
call mvn clean install
call mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=url -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile="%~dp0\target\art-1-SNAPSHOT.zip" -DgroupId=com.g.g -DartifactId=art -Dversion=1-SNAPSHOT -DrepositoryId=... -DpomFile="pom.xml"
```

the dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.g.g</groupId>
<artifactId>art</artifactId>    
<version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>zip</type>
```

Comment: If the pom file is not available in remote repository maven does not create default pom for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the pom file exists in the remote repo.

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippet of the pom with the dependency in question?  Also post the command you are running

Comment: try to change zip to jar (in pom and rename file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both the zip and the pom, you may specify them both as dependencies.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.g.g</groupId>
<artifactId>art</artifactId>    
<version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>zip</type> 

<dependency>
<groupId>com.g.g</groupId>
<artifactId>art</artifactId>    
<version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>pom</type>
```

Another way to do it if you don't want to specify the pom as a dependency: the Maven dependency plugin has a [get mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) that allows downloading of named artifacts from a remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the `packaging` in the `pom.xml` differs from the packaging of the dependency.  While pom.xml has the packaging as `pom`, the actual dependency packaging is `zip`.

Try changing the `<packaging>` in `pom.xml` to `zip` and see if addresses the issue.